# Downloading speed extremely slow in IIS for ASP.NET Core 5 Blazor server application

Tags: asp.net, iis, blazor-server-side, iis-10

I am extremely sad and couldn't find the solution from last 1 week so I end up asking help here.

I am hosting my business platform on IIS Server running on Windows Server 2021.

I am using server port speed of 10 gb/ps and I have 125 GB ram and 25 cores.

When a user downloads a file from my website, I am getting the server speed of just 100 kbps maximum 500 kbps.

My internet speed is 200 mbps and I am getting the same speed on my PC from the online network speed test.

Please help me to get the highest possible downloading speed on my server, must be I lacking something but I tried all possible things to speedup the server speed.

I am getting this speed in file downloading where I am getting 4-5 mbps  when I download anything from google drive-

[image]

Comment: Is your PC in the same network as the server, if so what speed can the PC download from the server at?

Comment: Hello @Tom , I am getting download speed of 20 mbps when I download the file from my server but when I download from my pc I am getting  200-300 kbps speed only. Can you please help me with the IIS seeting that is causing this problem?

Comment: 1. Microsoft never has "Windows Server 2021", so I wonder what exactly you are using. 2. When you said "my website" or "the server", where exactly is the hosting environment? A machine hosted by a service provider (AWS/Azure or similar)? Or just a machine of your own exposed to the internet? When describing a network related issue, the key is to show the actual network topology (with all related devices and links). 3. ASP.NET Core 5 is end of life, so you should migrate to .NET 6, though that's less relevant to this download speed issue.

Comment: The bandwidth is not equivalent to the performance that an Internet user actually gets. The Internet is a large series of network connections of variety of speeds between the server and browser. So you need to look at bottlenecks within the network layer itself.